# MySQL: Select if not in (unless stock > 0)

Tags: mysql

Just have a quick question about MySQL. I'm trying to select products from a table. There are product statuses such as withdrawn, discontinued, etc that I only want to show if their stock is greater than zero. I'm just having trouble getting what I'd put for the stock > 0 part (this is an example of what I'm thinking - not actual column and table names):

```
SELECT * FROM producttable
WHERE status NOT IN('Withdrawn', 'Discontinued')
(UNLESS Stock > 0)
```

Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show sample data and expected results?  That will clarify the logic.

Answer (score 0):

You want `and`. I think this is the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM producttable
WHERE status IN ('Withdrawn', 'Discontinued') and Stock > 0;
```

EDIT:

Oh, I think you want to show *all* statuses, except for the ones in the list.  Then only show those when stock > 0.  This query does that:

```
SELECT *
FROM producttable
WHERE status NOT IN ('Withdrawn', 'Discontinued') or Stock > 0;
```

Comment: OP seems wanted to show those statuses when `stock > 0` otherwise no.

Comment: Wouldn't this omit all discontinued or withdrawn products regardless of what their stock is? I want to show products with a status of withdrawn or discontinued if their stock is greater than 0, otherwise don't show them at all. Sorry if my question isn't clear, it's a hard one to decribe!

Comment: @CodeMonkey13 . . . The first query does what you want, according to your comment.

Comment: Sorry Gordon, just saw that one now (I only saw the OR one). There are statuses other than withdrawn and discontinued that I do want to show though, so it seems that I'm looking for a mixture of these two queries

Comment: Sorry again Gordon! My brain was telling me that this query would select all statuses with a stock greater than 0 unless they were 'withdrawn' or 'discontinued'. This is what I'm looking for, thanks!